# Selected folder path in VS code workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to get the(uri/path) of the currently opened folder in VS code workspace?

Comment: A context is needed. In most cases you can query that from `workspace.getWorkspaceFolder()` https://github.com/vscode-restructuredtext/vscode-restructuredtext/blob/128.0.0/src/features/utils/configuration.ts#L214

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But for me, I don't have a way to find about the resource(type Uri). I have a workspace that has many folders and I want to create a file in a selected folder using the "workspace.fs" API.